# ViewPager with viewpager inside releases memory really late which causes outofmemory

Tags: android, memory, xamarin, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager, managed by a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Inside the fragments of this viewpager, there's another viewpager that uses a PagerAdapter (named GalleryAdapter). This "GalleryAdapter" returns imageviews.

I don't know what to do here. The memory of the bitmaps gets released while scrolling but it happens really late, I'm testing on a oneplus one device and the allocated memory gets cleared around 90 MB allocated memory. after that garbage collection, it starts at 20 MB again and grows over 120 MB . In the end i get a memory exception.

I personally think that i should recycle the bitmaps. but when i recycle the image after setimagebitmap on the imageview, i get the error: trying to use a recycled bitmap.

I don't want to use a library cause i want to know what i'm doing wrong

```
public class GalleryAdapter: PagerAdapter
{
    Context context; 
    List<ArticleImageVO> _data;

    public GalleryAdapter (Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        _data = new List<ArticleImageVO> ();
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem (Android.Views.ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
        imageView.SetData (_data [position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).AddView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    public override bool IsViewFromObject (Android.Views.View view, Java.Lang.Object @object)
    {
        return view == ((ImageView) @object);
    }

    public override void DestroyItem (Android.Views.ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object @object)
    {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)((ImageView)@object).Drawable;
        if (bitmapDrawable != null && bitmapDrawable.Bitmap != null)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.Bitmap;
            bitmap.Recycle ();
        }
        ((ViewPager) container).RemoveView(((ImageView)@object) );
    }


    public override int Count 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _data.Count;
        }
    }

    public void SetData(List<ArticleImageVO> data)
    {
        _data.Clear ();
        _data.AddRange (data);
    }

}
```

The adapter from the viewpager that contains the above gallery viewpager:

```
public class ArticleDetailAdapter: FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    NewsController _newsController = NewsController.Instance;

    public ArticleDetailAdapter (FragmentManager fm) : base (fm)
    {
    }


    public override Fragment GetItem (int position)
    {
        ArticleDetailFragment fragment = new ArticleDetailFragment ();
        fragment.SetArguments(_newsController.ArticlesList[position]);
        return fragment;
    }

    public override int Count 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _newsController.ArticlesList.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

The fragment from the ViewPagerAdapter above: